# the distribution function of $g(X)$ where $g$ is increasing and differentiable on intervals $A_i$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X: \Omega \to \Bbb R$ be a random variable, such that $Im(X)$ can be writted as $ Im(X)= \displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}{A_i}$ be a disjoint union of intervals. Let $g: Im(X) \to \Bbb Y\subset R$ be a function such that $g$ is increasing and bijective  on each $A_i$ with it's image. Can I find the distribution function of $g(X)$ in terms of the distribution function of $X$?.

Let $B_i = X^{-1}(A_i)$ Then
$$P(\omega \in \Omega:g(X(\omega))\le x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{P(\omega \in B_i :g(X)\le x)}$$